# How to stop a service on multiple azure vms?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to run an azure cli command to stop the print service on all azure vms? Has anyone got some example code I could use?

Comment: Microsoft's docs are a good start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: however i need the code to do multiple vms, i can run that code ok on one but i want to get a list of all vms then stop a service on them all

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample using powershell:

```
# script.ps1
#   param(
#       [string]$arg1,
#       [string]$arg2
#   )
#   Write-Host This is a sample script with parameters $arg1 and $arg2

az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name win-vm -g my-resource-group \
    --scripts @script.ps1 --parameters "arg1=somefoo" "arg2=somebar"
```

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#:~:text=Go%20to%20a%20VM%20in,Choose%20a%20command%20to%20run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20a%20VM%20in,Choose%20a%20command%20to%20run).

Comment: thats for one vm? how do i get it to do multiple vms?

Comment: add the vm name  / RG to a map or array and iterate over it

Comment: yes thats the sample code im after - can someone post an example of how to do that?